# Div slideLeft.. Like slideDown or slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to slideLeft a div with jquery.. But like slideDown and slideUp or slideToggle.. How Can I do?

Comment: Try using [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick jQuery plugin that might help ?

```
jQuery.fn.slideLeftHide = function( speed, callback ) {
    this.animate({ 
        width: "hide", 
        marginLeft: "hide", 
        marginRight: "hide" 
    }, speed, callback ); 
}

jQuery.fn.slideLeftShow = function( speed, callback ) { 
    this.animate( { 
        width: "show", 
        marginLeft: "show", 
        marginRight: "show" 
    }, speed, callback ); 
}
```

To be used like so:

```
$("#elemID").slideLeftHide(300);
```

and a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VN8es/1/) for demonstation!

Answer (score 1):

Make an animation that use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to reduce the width to 0:

```
$('#my-id').animate({ width : 0 }, 1000); // slide left the div
```

Slide right is more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

This can work if your div has an overflow:hidden

```
$("#test").animate({width:0},500,function(){$(this).hide()})
```

Comment: You need the hide there specially if your div have borders. If not you can use @WouterJ's solution